# Insert values in table depending on values of another table mysql

Tags: mysql

Well my problem is like this:
I have to work with a database that has the tables `'user'` and `'phone'`:
Tha connection between  these tables is with the key `'iduser'` in table user and `'user'` in table phone.
In the table phone I have 98 entries and in the table user I have 1240 entries, how I can complete the 1240 with a default value in table phone using the iduser of table user without repeat the entries that exist now?

Is there a way to do that? I have to do it because I would only do a query instead 2 or 3.
Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undenstard your question correctly, this problem can be explained using the below simplified example:
There are the following records in table `users`:

```
| iduser |
|--------|
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      4 |
|      5 |
```

and there are the following records in table `phone` only for two users:

```
| user |       phone |
|------|-------------|
|    2 | 123-343-444 |
|    5 | 222-444-363 |
```

and you want to insert records with some "default" phone, say `111-222-333` for users which are not in that table (users 1, 3 and 4), and in the end the table should look like this:

```
| user |       phone |
|------|-------------|
|    1 | 111-222-333 |
|    2 | 123-343-444 |
|    3 | 111-222-333 |
|    4 | 111-222-333 |
|    5 | 222-444-363 |
```

If yes, then use the following query:

```
INSERT INTO phone( user, phone )
SELECT iduser, '111-222-333'
FROM user
WHERE iduser NOT IN ( SELECT user FROM phone );
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94158/2

Comment: Thanks!! It was so useful what I'm doing.