# How can I avoid filling database tables with default entries for an entity?

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, relational-database

In my application, I need to capture settings values for a certain entity called "Thing". There is a default value for each setting but the user can override these if needed. I have the following tables to capture the information:

```
Things table
ID  | Name
-----------
1   | Thing1
2   | Thing2

ThingSettingsDescriptions Table
ID   | SettingDescription   | Default
---------------------------------------
1    | Colour                | Blue
2    | Size                  | Medium
3    | Temperature           | Hot


ThingSettingsValues Table
ID   | ThingID   | ThingSettingsID   | Value
---------------------------------------------
1    |  1        |  1                | Blue
2    |  1        |  2                | Medium
3    |  1        |  3                | Hot
4    |  2        |  1                | Blue
5    |  2        |  2                | Medium
6    |  2        |  3                | Hot
```

In sample data above Thing1 and Thing2 have default settings - hence the entries in the ThingSettingsValues are repeated for each thing. This seems a bit inefficient to me.

Is there a way to avoid repeating these default values for each thing?

The closest question I've found to mine is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787654/insert-values-in-table-depending-on-values-of-another-table-mysql) but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Another option I thought of would be to only store non default values in the ThingSettingsValues table. This means in the application when the settings for a thing are required, we check the ThingSettingsValues table, if it contains no entries for that thing, read the default values from the ThingSettingsDescriptions table  then use these default settings values instead. 
This would work but means the database does not explicitly capture where to get settings values for a thing if there are no entries in the ThingSettingsValues table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At first instance it does seem like redundancy(duplication of data) as the ThingSettingsDescriptions table and ThingSettingsValues table have values repeated for the default entries.

However, if one looks closely this is *not* redundancy. The reason being that the *seemingly* repeated values in ThingSettingsValues(Values) table serve an entirely different purpose than that in the ThingSettingsDescriptions(Descriptions) tables. For every setting-id in Descriptions table there is a default value assigned. I.e. a fall back value if there is no value for this setting for some thing in the Values table.

On the other hand the Values table contains all the possible options for those settings out of which one happens to be the default. If some "thing" does *not* have any setting entry in the Values table then the default values are the fallback values on which the application falls. So, the purpose of values in the two tables is different and IMO current database design is good as there is no redundancy.